# One ajax handler or multiple handler?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

My webpage needs to send/receieve several ajax operations when being used. Currently I use one ajax handler to handle all events. All ajax requests are sent/received using this format "(type) | {json string}".

A piece of js code will handler the ajax requests/responses: parsing response text -> getting type -> select...case doing something in each type case.

This works but as ajax events grow there are too many cases like from 0 to 99. Well it's not likely to be an easy job for maintenance or further developing.

Maybe I need to split the single ajax handler to mulitiple ones? Then how does the browser know which ajax response should be sent to the specific handler?

Any advice is appreciated.

Currently the code looks like this: (one of the pages using simple javascript, no framework used)

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    var reply = decodeArray(xmlhttp.responseText);  //convert to json object and some other stuff 
                    switch (reply.type) {
                          case 0:
                          case 1:
                          ....

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the fundamental challenges with software engineering.  You have a task that you do repeatedly, but the details change slightly with each variation, so how do you reuse code and keep things clean....every substantial app has this problem.

You need to use a design approach that enforces good **Separation of Concerns**. I usually develop on API for my app that is completely separate from other parts of the app.   My API does one thing and one thing only -- it communicates with the server.

**It has no application specific code**.

This means I can reuse my api in different apps, if necessary.  It also means I can test my API independently of the app.

So lets say you need to do something like `loadObject`.  The applications sees

```
App.API = {
    loadObject: function(params, onSuccess, onFail) {...}
}
```

The key to keeping this decouples is the `onSuccess` and `onFail` callbacks.  The application that is using the API passes in these functions; so the API knows nothing of the application specific logic -- all it knows is that if fires these callbacks appropriately.  The callbacks are methods that take arguments that are the response data; all the API does is pass the response data to the callback.

Since most of the time, the details of your ajax calls have lots of common items, I also would create some sort of `XhrWrapper` that fires requests.  So in your `loadObjects` you would use your xhr helper to make the request

```
xhr.sendRequest(url, method, onSuccess, onFail);
```

This way all the tedium of firing xhrs is minimized.

Obviously, you can go further; for example, most of the time failure is bad, so my xhr wrapper will have a default onFail implementation, and specific API methods can pass in an override, only if it makes sense.